# Basic Slope-Intercept Form y=mx+b

Tags: mathematical-physics, mathematics

The equation for a line forms a part of my physics work.

The equation is: **Y = mx+b**

To refresh myself, I watched the following [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u3spOO-m_Gg&ab_channel=TylerTarver) on the formula. However, at **3:15** I went off in the wrong direction when I tried to get variable b by itself. I understand it works the teacher's way, but: **why am I not allowed to -b from both sides, and then -6 from both sides?**

When I continued doing it my potentially incorrect way, my answer became b=-2 which was correct, aside from the wrong sign as it should be positive.

It might have also been possible to have divided by 6 on both sides, but then the answer would become b=4/6 which is a decimal number not close to the correct answer.

I feel that little bits of missing knowledge are holding me back.

Comment: It would be good if you showed the steps you took to find $b=-2$. That way you could receive more useful feedback.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because - despite being a part of your physics study - this is a question about mathematics, not physics.  It would be more at home on [MathSE](https://math.stackexchange.com) .

Comment: @lee Voting to close because a question belongs on a different site **is** a vote to migrate. See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10249/what-is-migration-and-how-does-it-work).

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't aware of that.

Comment: This question failed migration because the asker is currently blocked from asking question on math.SE. Please do not ask questions here just because you're blocked from asking them on the site where they actually belong, this will only get you blocked on our site as well.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Teacher's way:

$\quad y=mx+b$

$\quad6=(\frac{1}{2})8 + b$

$\quad6=4 + b$

$\,-4\,-4$

$\quad2= b$

Your way (-b, -6, fixed):

$\quad y=mx+b$

$\quad6=(\frac{1}{2})8 + b$

$\quad6=4 + b$

$\,-b\qquad-b$

$\quad6-b=4$

$\,-6\qquad-6$

$\,-b=-2$

$\quad b=2$

Your way (-b, divide by 6, gets stuck):

$\quad y=mx+b$

$\quad6=(\frac{1}{2})8 + b$

$\quad6=4 + b$

$\quad\frac{6}{6}=\frac{4+b}{6}$ (stuck)

OR

$\quad6=4 + b$

$\,-b\qquad-b$

$\quad6-b=4$

$\quad\frac{6-b}{6}=\frac{4}{6}$ (stuck)

Comment: That was a very good answer, thank you I have marked it as complete. I feel stupid now for my question as I knew a lot of this, I just went into space. How comes you can change -b=-2 to b=2 on the first my way approach?

Comment: You're not actually changing anything, those are equivalent. $-b = -2$ so $ (-1)b=(-1)2$, thus $b=2$.

Comment: @Monopole You mean because (-1) * b = (-1) * 2 we can further simplify it by dividing each side by -1 or something? o.O

Comment: @securityauditor that's exactly it

Comment: Exactly, you can divide both sides by -1. Or you can multiply both sides by -1 then again you will get $b=2$.

Comment: @Monopole But why did you say they are equivalent though? Sorry, I suck at maths terms, so it might mean something obvious. P.S I love your username, reminds me of monopole magnets.

Comment: You have $-b = -2$ and if you multiply or divide this equation by -1 (or any finite, non-zero number), you don't change anything b is still gonna be 2.

Comment: It's quite easy @securityauditor. For example: If $2a=2b$, you can divide both sides by 2 to get $a=b$. That doesn't change anything. It's called the _"multiplication and division property of equality"_ which states that _if you multiply or divide both sides of an equation by the same number, then both sides are still equal_. I suggest you to learn these(and other properties of equality) on google as this site is meant for question and answers that have got something to do with physics.

Comment: $\dfrac{6}{6}=\dfrac{4+b}{6}$ isn't 'stuck.' $$1=\dfrac23+\dfrac b6\implies \dfrac b6=1-\dfrac23\implies\dfrac b6=\dfrac13\implies b=2$$ Sure it's a bit of back and forth because we multiply by 6 after we first divided by it, but by no means are we stuck. Same with your second option.